# How to find which mountpoint current working directory of a process correspond to?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, process, proc

I have a program *a.out* running from */tmp/test*. If I list `/proc/$(pgrep a.out)/cwd`, it is a symbolic link to */tmp/test*.

Now, I bind */mnt/othertest* onto */tmp/test* with `mount -o bind /mnt/othertest /tmp/test`. Thus, this new mount is stacked and old */tmp/test* is hidden.

Still, since *a.out* was launched before mount command, it has access to the old path.

The problem I want to tackle is how to know if a process with *cwd* set to */tmp/test* refers to the directory from */mnt/othertest* or not.

For opened files, it is easy, I can use *fdinfo* from *proc* pseudo-filesyste and read the mount id, but I did not find such information for *cwd*. I could  check the start time of the process and compare it with the time when mount was launched, but because of possible forks it could be wrong.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [Determine what device a directory is located on](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128471)

Comment: Also possibly interesting (unless I'm misunderstanding the question): [How to get mount point of filesystem containing given file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/90252)

Comment: @Kusalananda It is not related since my directory is hidden by the stack from the new mount. And I want to know if it refers to the old device or not.

Comment: Does a process have the old directory as its current directory? In that case, the current directory refers to the hidden directory. Can't test this as I don't have a Unix with bind mounts available ATM.

Comment: Yes, since the process is run before the mount command. I took a bind mount as example but it is the same for old kindd of mounts (can be a loop mount with an img file created with dd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `stat(2)` on `/proc/PID/cwd` and on the other directory and compare them by the `device:inode` tuple.

Example (notice that unless given the `-L` switch, the `stat(1)` utility will perform a `lstat(2)` system call instead of a `stat(2)`):

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo /tmp/bar /tmp/baz
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ echo $$
20890

# mount -B /tmp/bar /tmp/foo
# stat -Lc %d:%i /proc/20890/cwd
2055:1835959

# stat -Lc %d:%i "$(readlink /proc/20890/cwd)" /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
2055:1843068
2055:1843068
2055:1843068

# umount /tmp/foo
# stat -Lc %d:%i /tmp/foo
2055:1835959
```

Just like the files under `/proc/PID/fd`, `/proc/PID/cwd` is not a real symlink -- an `open(2)`, `stat(2)`, etc. will not follow its target, but act directly on the actual object it refers to.

Comment: Nice! I did not even think about `stat` since `ls` was giving me the info. Thanks to the deferencing from `stat` and thank you.